# Cannot install datacube-explorer 2.5.4 version

Tags: open-data-cube

When I try to install datacube-explorer v2.5.4 after extract it to a directory, enter the directory, and pip install . I have this error

[image]

Comment: Did you try cloning the repository and installing from the cloned copy instead? `setuptools-scm` is probably looking for git tags.

Comment: Please cut&paste error messages into the body of your Question. Posting a red-on-black image doesn't allow many to read, much less others to search for your Question.

Answer (score 1):

The information it's showing in the error message is correct:

> Make sure you're either building from a fully intact git repository or PyPI tarballs. Most other sources (such as GitHub's tarballs, a git checkout without the .git folder) don't contain the necessary metadata and will not work.

It currently needs to be installed via a Git checkout rather than a tarball due to our usage of `setuptools-scm`, which reads the version information from Git on install.

Eg.

```
git clone https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-explorer.git
cd datacube-explorer
pip install .
```

(we should probably make this more obvious in the readme. We do plan to [push it to PyPi](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-explorer/pull/271) eventually to make install even easier)